# Complete Class at Cursor Not Working

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-xe2, code-completion, aqtime

I've been widely making use of the Complete Class at Cursor function in Delphi, in 2010 and in XE2. Recently, after installing Update 4 for XE2, the Complete Class at Cursor stopped working. After doing some research, I found that uninstalling "AQTime" would fix the issue. So I did that (had to re-install Delphi just to remove it) and sure enough it started working again.

Except, today, it suddenly stopped again. AQTime is not installed, and I haven't done anything in the IDE at all which (as far as I know) could possibly cause this. I haven't installed/uninstalled any packages, changed any library paths, not even changing any settings. It just suddenly stopped working in the middle of my development. Was working one minute, and not the next. I've restarted Delphi, restarted my PC, and even tried in a brand new project. It just will not work anymore.

Anyone know why this stopped working? How can I make it work again? It's an extremely helpful tool which I use all the time.

Comment: I don't know why... as a kind of workaround, you can setup [cnpack](http://www.cnpack.org/showdetail.php?id=715&lang=en) which has is own completion :/

Comment: The problem seems to be on and off, it's just random as far as I can see. I don't see any patterns.

Comment: At least I can see the problem is per IDE instance. I might be working normally once, then it quits working. If I close/re-open RAD studio XE2, sometimes it starts working again, sometimes it isn't. Then a few days later it works again. Very strange.

Comment: Jerry I've been facing this same issue so I downloaded delphi distiller and disabled all packages related to AQTime, maybe even uninstalling it some bpls are loaded in your IDE and is causing the problem. Here it works fine.

Comment: At least I know I'm not the only one with these problems, thanks, gonna try that out soon.

Comment: I have come across the same problem on several occasions and found that changing teh delay time makes no difference. Perhaps you should 'unaccept' the answer? It worked for you but it is not an objectove resolution. On that not either is uninstalling Smartbear AQTime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Had the exact same issue in XE2/Update 4. Did the following (without uninstalling AQTime) and it came back.

Tools > Options >Editor Options > Code Insight

Verified the Code Completion was checked (it was), then changed the Delay to Low (was set to None) > OK

Code Completion in my IDE started working again.

Comment: I'm not sure that the Delay setting was the cause, but it seems that just making a change in the Code Insight section and applying the change caused the Code Completion settings to reset. Not digging any more... it works now for me.

Comment: This issue has started happening to me now as well (after recently installing AQtime). Applied this change, tried toggling various options in the Code Completion options on/off, restarting the IDE - nothing resolved this for me. Next step is to uninstall AQtime itself...

Comment: I have done these steps and code completion did not come back working.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, but it was solved after uninstalling **Smartbear AQTime** from the windows uninstaller. (close Delphi first)

No need to reinstall Delphi.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem in Delphi Berlin.  None of the above worked for me.  I also tried regenerating the .dproj file but that also did not help.

The one thing that has worked (so far) is installing the excellent IDEFixPack for Delphi Berlin. [Delphi IDE Fix Pack](https://www.idefixpack.de/blog/ide-tools/ide-fix-pack/)

Please let me take this opportunity also for a quick moan.  Code completion is an absolutely essential feature of Delphi and it is very slow and flaky at best. Embarcadero (if you are listening) - please focus on making these core features much more robust.

Comment: I haven't had this issue ever since I've upgraded from XE2. I've gone through XE7, XE8, 10 Seattle, and 10.1 Berlin, and never faced this issue since.

Comment: I suspect that the IDE is getting a bit overwhelmed by the size of my program with many units. It works OK on small sample projects.  PS was also using AQTime (8.7) and had uninstalled the IDE integration but that made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Unstalling the AQTime8.20 integration in the IDE solve the problem for me too - used AQtime outside the IDE anyway.